# Active Directory update from Console App throwing Object Reference Error, where the value was null previously

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have written a console app to fetch data from Database and update Active Directory. It is not able to replace null values already present in active directory, throwing "Object Reference is not set to an instance.."

I am handling null values fetched from DB and replacing them with "-". So I'm not passing any null value to AD.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName)) { lastName = "-"; }
entry.Properties[ADProperties.LASTNAME].Value = lastName;
```

I want to update Active Directory thoroughly (even if there is any null present in AD).

Comment: That means that something is `null` and you are using it as if it was not. You will have to debug your code, set a breakpoint on that line, and see what is `null`. From what I see, it could be `entry` or `ADProperties`.

Comment: Just to be clear: It doesn't actually save the value to AD until you use `entry.CommitChanges()`. So those two lines of code don't talk to AD at all, which means your problem is in your C# code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in trying to save null or invalid value in the Manager property.
To resolve this issue, I'm checking whether the value is valid or not.
In case, it is coming null or invalid from DB, I'm using `.Clear()` function.
Below is the sample code:

```
try
        {
            if (entry.Properties[propertyName].Value == null)
            {
                if (dbValue != "")
                {
                    //Value Null in AD, but Not Null in DB. AD value to be updated with DB value
                    //Write Log
                    entry.Properties[propertyName].Value = dbValue;
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Value Not Null in AD
                if (!dbValue.Equals(entry.Properties[propertyName].Value))
                {
                    // Value Not Null in AD And Not Matching With DB Value
                    //Write Log
                    if (dbValue != "")
                    {
                        //Value Present in AD & DB Both, but not same. AD Value to be updated with DB Value
                        entry.Properties[propertyName].Value = dbValue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Value Present in AD but blank in DB. AD Value to be cleared.
                        entry.Properties[propertyName].Clear();
                    }
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Write Log
            return 0;
        }
```